# Chrome extension context menu - modify text box selection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am making a Google Chrome extension that has tools to quickly make text reversed, upside-down, rainbow, etc and have browser action with those tools working perfectly but I also want a context menu that allows the user to use one of those tools on a text box/area selection. I have a lot of spare time because of school holidays but I just can't think of how to do it and I can't find the answer on Google or Stack Overflow. I figured out how to create a context menu and I just need to know how I can modify the selected text from the background script.

TL;DR: How can I modify the selected text in a text box/area with a context menu?

(I am also using jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [jQuery caret plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jcaret/).

Code may look like below (untested)

replaceselector.js:

```
function replaceSelection(selector, replaceText) {
  var input = $(selector);
  var text = input.text();
  input.text(text.substr(0, input.caret().start) + replaceText + text.substr(input.caret().end);
}
```

Inject [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to the target tab then call execScript from your background page

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file: "jquery.min.js"} function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file: "jquery.caret.1.02.min.js"} function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file: "replaceSelector.js"} function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {code: "replaceSelection('#myInputBox', 'Replace String');"});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but basically what I want to know is how to do that from the background script. I haven't really developed Chrome extensions for a while and I have never made extensions that modify the current page. Do I need to inject code into the page or is the some way to access the page's DOM from the background script?

Comment: Updated my answer with content script execution samples